# Not able to scroll an HTML page on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

When I load it from safari or chrome, it works fine. Also, before adding margin to .infoBox, it is able to scroll but elements overlap. When I do, the .infoBox is cutoff on the bottom of the page on any mobile device from iphone to ipad pro and scrolling is turned off. I would like to know how to position the elements properly so that they would not overlap and the page could be scrolled.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Text Text Text </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css">

    <style>
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:"Arial";
  background: linear-gradient(#141e30, #243b55);
  overflow: hidden;
  size: 120%;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white; 
  font-size: 19px;
}
#wrapper {
    min-width: 300px; 
    overflow:scroll;
    position: relative;
}

.claimBox {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.claimBox h2 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.claimBox .infoBox {
  position: relative;
}

.claimBox .infoBox input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.claimBox .infoBox label {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.claimBox .infoBox input:focus ~ label,
.claimBox .infoBox input:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.claimBox form a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  margin-top: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px
}

.claimBox a:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
              0 0 25px #03e9f4,
              0 0 50px #03e9f4,
              0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

.claimBox a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.claimBox a span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-anim1 {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.claimBox a span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .25s
}

@keyframes btn-anim2 {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.claimBox a span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .5s
}

@keyframes btn-anim3 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

.claimBox a span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .75s
}

@keyframes btn-anim4 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .claimBox {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-bottom: px;
  }
  #wrapper {
    width: width;
    display: inline;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .claimBox {
    overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  #wrapper {
    display: inline;
  }
}



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="classBlock" id="wrapper">
        <h3>  Text Text </h3>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="1"> Lorem ipsum </p>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="2"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  </p>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="3"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="4"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  </p>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="5"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  </p>
    </div>
    <div class="claimBox">
  <h2>Text Text Text Text Text Text </h2>
  <form>
    <div class="infoBox">
      <input type="text" name="" required="">
      <label>Text Text Text Text Text Text </label>
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox">
      <input type="text" name="" required="">
      <label>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </label>
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox">
      <input type="email" name="" required="">
      <label>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </label>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      Submit
    </a>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `overflow: hidden` inside `body` is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Line 24: `body { overflow: hidden; }` causes the issue. Overflow: hidden does not just hdie the scrollbar but also disable scroll ability.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Text Text Text </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Design.css">

    <style>
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: static;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:"Arial";
  background: linear-gradient(#141e30, #243b55);
  /* overflow: hidden; <- ISSUE */
  size: 120%;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white; 
  font-size: 19px;
}
#wrapper {
    min-width: 300px; 
    overflow:scroll;
    position: relative;
}

.claimBox {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.claimBox h2 {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.claimBox .infoBox {
  position: relative;
}

.claimBox .infoBox input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
}
.claimBox .infoBox label {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.claimBox .infoBox input:focus ~ label,
.claimBox .infoBox input:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.claimBox form a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .5s;
  margin-top: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px
}

.claimBox a:hover {
  background: #03e9f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
              0 0 25px #03e9f4,
              0 0 50px #03e9f4,
              0 0 100px #03e9f4;
}

.claimBox a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.claimBox a span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes btn-anim1 {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.claimBox a span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .25s
}

@keyframes btn-anim2 {
  0% {
    top: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    top: 100%;
  }
}

.claimBox a span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: 0;
  right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .5s
}

@keyframes btn-anim3 {
  0% {
    right: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

.claimBox a span:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
  animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: .75s
}

@keyframes btn-anim4 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100%;
  }
  50%,100% {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .claimBox {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-bottom: px;
  }
  #wrapper {
    width: width;
    display: inline;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .claimBox {
    overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  #wrapper {
    display: inline;
  }
}



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="classBlock" id="wrapper">
        <h3>  Text Text </h3>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="1"> Lorem ipsum </p>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="2"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  </p>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="3"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="4"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  </p>
        <p class="offerDesc" id="5"> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  </p>
    </div>
    <div class="claimBox">
  <h2>Text Text Text Text Text Text </h2>
  <form>
    <div class="infoBox">
      <input type="text" name="" required="">
      <label>Text Text Text Text Text Text </label>
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox">
      <input type="text" name="" required="">
      <label>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </label>
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox">
      <input type="email" name="" required="">
      <label>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </label>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      Submit
    </a>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```